# Javascript function counting when using div class name, but not div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of 3 checkboxes that is using javascript to validate that all 3 boxes are selected before the apply button is enabled. I am currently using the following function to check the classname count of `.qualify-point`. However I need to use the ID like `#qualify-point`. However when I make this change inside `isAllChecked` it only counts up to 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
const $applyButton = $("#qualify-apply__button");
const $checkBoxes = $(".qualify-point input:checkbox");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $applyButton.attr("disabled", true);
    $applyButton.click(apply);
    $checkBoxes.change(checkIfCanApply);
    $applyButtonSidebar.attr("disabled", true);
});

function isAllChecked() {
  console.log($(".qualify-point input:checkbox:checked").length, "count")
  return $(".qualify-point input:checkbox:checked").length === 3;
}

function checkIfCanApply () {
    if(isAllChecked()) {
        $applyButton.attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $applyButton.attr("disabled", true);
    }
}

function apply(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isAllChecked()) {
        localStorage.setItem("initial_application_data", JSON.stringify({ loan: { do_you_qualify: true } }));
        window.location = "/apply";
    }
    return;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="qualify-list__wrapper">
                    <div class="qualify-point" id="qualify-point">
                      <span class="qualify-point__label">Min 6 months in business</span>
                      <div class="checkbox-white-bg">
                        <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-white-bg__input" checked="checked" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
                        <label aria-label="minimum 6 months" tabindex="0" for="checkbox-1"
                          class="checkbox__label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qualify-point" id="qualify-point">
                      <span class="qualify-point__label">Active ABN or ACN</span>
                      <div class="checkbox-white-bg">
                        <input id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-white-bg__input" name="checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
                        <label aria-label="active abn checkbox" tabindex="0" for="checkbox-2"
                          class="checkbox__label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qualify-point" id="qualify-point">
                      <span class="qualify-point__label">Min $5,000 monthly revenue</span>
                      <div class="checkbox-white-bg">
                        <input id="checkbox-3" class="checkbox-white-bg__input" name="checkbox-3" type="checkbox">
                        <label aria-label="min $5000 monthly checkbox" tabindex="0" for="checkbox-3"
                          class="checkbox__label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qualify-apply">
                      <button id="qualify-apply__button" class="button"
                        disabled="true">
                        <span>Apply Now</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple `id="qualify-point"`

Comment: Well - just to clarify it is **possible** to have multiple ids with the same name but definitely not recommended/good practice...

Answer (score 1):

I threw this in my testing environment and found that `$applyButtonSidebar.attr("disabled", true);`
was throwing undefined on $applyButtonSidebar. After commenting that out I was able to get a count to 3 and the button activated.

[image: Checkboxes]

[image: Console]